# Drag-drop text into editable div which has multiple lines of text (and essentially inner elements)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to get this done for a couple of days - however it seems that I need to reach out for some external help once again.

This is what I have been tasked with. I have to create a html text editor with some basic functionality. This is what it looks like:
[image]

This is all done manually - no external resources as far as we can - using React and Typescript/ES6.

Now, the email body is a DIV, which is editable.

```
<div id="EditableDIV" className="textarea" contentEditable={true} onDragOver={this.onDragOver} onDrop={this.drop}></div>
```

I want to drop some text into this as a start - but I eventually want to drop a HtmlElement so that I can style the item that was dropped. (you know, to look nice - with a cute little remove button, etc) However, I want to focus on only dropping text for now.

This is the code that fires when I drag an item:

```
<div className="fields">
    {this.state.model.fields.map(function(field, index) {
        return (
            <div key={index} className="field" draggable={true} onDragStart={(e) => self.dragField(e, field)}>
                <span className="dragText">{field.text}</span>
                <span className="dragIcon fa fa-arrows"></span>
            </div>);
    })}
</div>

dragField(e: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>, field: Field) {
    e.dataTransfer.setData(
        "text/html",
        '[%' + field.text + '%]'
    );
}
```

Here is the code that fires when it gets dragged over the Email Body editable DIV.

```
onDragOver = (e) => {
    this._caretPosition = document.caretRangeFromPoint(e.pageX,e.pageY).startOffset;
}
```

Here, I am trying to keep track of the caret position. So that I can (attempt to...) drop my text at a certain location.

```
drop = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let sel = document.getSelection();
    let data = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/html");
    let startString = sel.focusNode.textContent.substring(0, this._caretPosition);
    let endString = sel.focusNode.textContent.substring(this._caretPosition, sel.focusNode.textContent.length);
    this._container.textContent = `${startString}${data}${endString}`;
}
```

Now, something to keep in mind, is that if I do something like this:
[image]

The underlying HTML changes to something like this:
[image]

And I think that this is also causing a problem with my drag-drop solution because there are now also elements being created as the user types.

When I drag my field, I can see my cursor move:
[image]

However, after letting go of the mouse button to initiate the drop, this is what happens:
[image]

Look - the Field dropped at the last caret position (last spot where I typed). It seems like the drop does not respect my location. Does this have something to do with the

> document.getSelection()?

If I click between the text where I want to insert the dropped field first, and then do another drop, it seems to work SORT OF:

[image]

[image]

[image]

What just happened was that it placed the text in the correct ROW, BUT also at the caret position the element was dropped at (from the start of the row).

Is there perhaps a way to set the caret position to the one being indicated as it is being dropped? Or a better way to get the caret position?

Thanks in advance!